# Question from quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$f(x) = –x^2+ 2px – (3p + 4)$$. If $f(x)$ is positive for atleast one real $x$ then the smallest positive integral value of $p$ is:

(1)     $2$

(2)     $3$

(3) $4$

(4) $5$

What I did, Since for atleast one value of $x$ ,$f(x)$>0 
Or,$$ x^2- 2px + (3p + 4)<0$$

Now ,how should I proceed ?

Comment: Please keep the hints or explanation comprehensible as I am a 12th grade student.thanks

Comment: I'd suggest substituting those values in for $p$ and seeing what happened. Here we could use the discriminant to help us a bit, or we could graph them to see what happens.

Comment: Since $f$ is positive for some $x$ and opens downward. You can assume that there are two real roots to the equation $f=0$. Use the quadratic formula to generate these roots as functions of $p$. The discriminant(expression under the radical sign in the formula) must necessarily be positive. Examination of this term will allow you to finish the problem.

Comment: @JEM after checking the discriminant I get,

Comment: (p-4)(p+1)>0...what should I do now ?

Comment: I don't get a minimum value through this because it goes down to negative infinity ,right?

Comment: @YashLekhwani: You have it. There is only one choice that satisfies that.

Comment: Oh yeah..I'm sorry I'm speaking non sense it says positive integral value..:)My bad..thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Complete the square" to get:

$$\begin{align}-x^2 + 2px - (3p + 4) &= -(x^2 -2px + (3p + 4))\\
&= -(( x - p)^2 + (3p+4) - p^2)\\ &= -(x-p)^2 + p^2 - 3p - 4\\
&= -(x-p)^2 + (p-4)(p+1)\end{align}$$

Since $-(x-p)^2 \le 0$ for all real $x$ and $p$, the maximum value of $-x^2 + 2px - (3p + 4)$ is $(p-4)(p+1)$. In other words,

$$-x^2 + 2px - (3p + 4) \le (p-4)(p+1)$$

with equality achieved at $x = p$.

Since we need $f(x)$ to be positive for at least one real value of $x$, it suffices to find $p$ for which the maximum value of $f(x)$ is positive. In other words, the required values of $p$ are:

$$(p - 4)(p +1) > 0$$

whose solution set is $p > 4$ or $p < -1$.

Hence the least possible positive integral value of $p$ is $5$.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.Although the method is nearly same as what I finally used,it made it more clear to me.@YiyuanLee.thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey!!Ur 17 too.All the very best wishes from me.Continue chasing your passions!!hehe..:)

Comment: No problem, thanks and all the best to you to! Since you are new to Math.SE : Do remember to mark any of the answers posted to your question as the solution via the tick beside it, if you found it sufficient and useful.